# Axios get request is in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have this Reactjs app, and it's consuming the **Marvel API**. But once it's running, it starts making the GET request and never stops anymore.

I've tried to use async/await and promise based configuration for my **axios** get method, but the result is the same: **ifinite request**

Main.js

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heroes: [],
      search: "",
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadHeroes();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.searc !== this.state.search) {
      this.loadHeroes();
    }
  }

  loadHeroes = async () => {
    const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC;
    const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE;
    const timestamp = Number(new Date());
    const hash = md5.create();
    hash.update(timestamp + PRIVATE_KEY + PUBLIC_KEY);

    const response = await api
      .get(
        `/characters?limit=10&ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results });
      });

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("State do search: ", this.state.search);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

//render method ommited
```

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public`
});

export default api;
```

See that in the URL, I've set the limit of 10 requests (this is an API pattern available). But even though, the problem occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your if-condition, `prevState.searc` will always be undefined since it doesnt exist and therefore does not equal `this.state.search`. `componentDidUpdate` checks condition (passes), runs logic, logic updates state, retriggers `componentDidUpdate` and the cycle is endless:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.searc !== this.state.search) {
      this.loadHeroes();
    }
  }
```

You probably meant:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.search !== this.state.search) {
      this.loadHeroes();
    }
  }
```